# How can refresh automatically expression view in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, lauterbach

I use Eclipse with Lauterbach for debugging . In Lauterbach I see variables in real time ( Variable is automatically refresh) , but in Eclipse in Expression view when i press Run the variables from expression view is changing values just if I press Refresh button.

How can I set Eclipse to refresh automatically expression view ?

Comment: You should edit the title of the question to sum up the contents, looking at the title alone says almost nothing about your issue.